# How to prevent my browser from showing "waiting for MyHostName" message during ajax Post/Get operation?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, browser, google-chrome

When you open a site with Chrome it shows a message in status bar telling "Waiting for MyHost name" plus it shows Ajax Loader circle in the caption of the tab. Now I have the following javascript function:

```
function listen_backend_client_requests() {
    $.get('/listen?cid=backend_client_requests', // an url to nginx http push channel, http connection stays opened for a long time until the actual data starts to arrive
    {},
    function(r) {
        alert('check');
        if (r == 'report_request') {
            report_request();
        }
        listen_backend_client_requests();
    }
    , 'json');
}
```

The "$.get(...)" operation is "long polling"(via nginx http push module). It doesn't receive data instantly but waits until the data is published to a channel. And during all this time (may take up to 15 minutes) Chrome shows 'waiting for My host name' in the lower left part of the window and also shows Ajax Loader circle. I dont want them to be shown not in Chrome but neither in any other browser and I have no idea how to do that...

P.S.

By the way, I know that google docs are using the same scheme, but some how their site causes the browser not to show the message. Any suggestions?

Comment: IMHO this is a bad idea. If a webpage could control, what my browser gives as status messages, I could download tons of data to the users PC, without let him knowing. My Operas default setting doesn't even allow the change of status-bar-content. Nor any else "strange" script-actions, like replacing the context-menu or changing window-size… I am the user - and its my browser, so let him tell me whats happening!

Comment: The browser shows that there's some activity on the page, when there isn't one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution to my problem in contrast to the following posts

[How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)
[Sending messages to server with Comet long-polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864359/sending-messages-to-server-with-comet-long-polling)
[Browers entering "busy" state on Ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259889/browers-entering-busy-state-on-ajax-request)

my problem was that I was starting the long poll ajax request before my page was actually loaded and this fact prevented browser from "waiting for" state...

Just start your long polling process after you have your page completely loaded...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting `window.status`? Although I'm not sure I would recommend it, it probably would do what you want. Just be sure to reset the status when appropriate.